# Getting Radius from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

So I have a PHP script that gets data from MySQL the `msg_location` uses the Point spatial data. I am trying to retrieve only the data that is only in the 10 mile radius. Below is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$lat = $_POST['latitude'];
$long = $_POST['longitude'];
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/php/database/main.php';
$records = $conn->query('SELECT message, X(msg_location), Y(msg_location), loved 
    FROM hidyn_msg WHERE 3963 * ACOS(
    SIN(RADIANS(X(msg_location))) * SIN(RADIANS(X(msg_location))) + COS(RADIANS(X(msg_location)))  * COS(RADIANS(:lat)) * COS(RADIANS(:long) - RADIANS(:long))) <= 10
 ORDER BY msg_date DESC');
    $stmt -> bindparam(':lat', $lat);
    $stmt -> bindparam(':long', $long);
    try{
        $records->execute();
        $results = $records->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(count($results) > 0):
            echo json_encode($results);
        endif;
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $stmtError = $stmt->errorInfo();
        $statusMSG= array('error'=>false, 'message' => "We had a issue creating and posting your message. Error: ", $e[0]);
        echo json_encode(statusMSG);
    }
?>
```

At the top recieves the GeoLocation of the user and post it to the php file to rerieve the data.

The error happens at $records->execute(); and I've tried changing the script to echo the error but it doesn't echo anything. The SQL works in the MySQL console and works great.

**Working Code:**
Help by RamRider

```
<?php
$lat = $_POST['latitude'];
$long = $_POST['longitude'];
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/php/database/main.php';
$sql = ('SELECT msg_date, message, loved
    FROM hidyn_msg WHERE
         msg_location = ((ACOS(SIN(:lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(X(msg_location) * PI() / 180) + 
         COS(:lat * PI() / 180) * COS(X(msg_location) * PI() / 180) * COS((:long - Y(msg_location)) * 
         PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) <= 10
 ORDER BY msg_date DESC');
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt -> bindparam(':lat', $lat);
    $stmt -> bindparam(':long', $long);
    try{
        $results = $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(count($results) > 0):
            echo json_encode($results);
        endif;
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $stmtError = $stmt->errorInfo();
        $statusMSG= array('error'=>false, 'message' => "We had a issue creating and posting your message. Error: ", $e[0]);
        echo json_encode(statusMSG);
    }
?>
```

Comment: you should not `query` and then `execute` - also to `execute` you need to first `prepare` the sql statement

Comment: @RamRaider I read somewhere for PDO you need to use the execute() function

Comment: no, you can choose different methods of querying the database according to your situation. When user input is expected then prepared statements and thus `execute` - with static sql queries you can opt for `query` method - but not both like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to my comment ( not tested ) it would typically be more like this:

```
<?php

    $lat = $_POST['latitude'];
    $long = $_POST['longitude'];

    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/php/database/main.php';

    $sql='select message, x(msg_location), y(msg_location), loved 
        from hidyn_msg where 3963 * acos(
        sin(radians(x(msg_location))) * sin(radians(x(msg_location))) + cos(radians(x(msg_location)))  * cos(radians(:lat)) * cos(radians(:long) - radians(:long))) <= 10
        order by msg_date desc';

        $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindParam(':lat', $lat);
        $stmt->bindParam(':long', $long);

        try{
            $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
            if(count($results) > 0):
                echo json_encode($results);
            endif;
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $stmtError = $stmt->errorInfo();
            $statusMSG= array('error'=>false, 'message' => "We had a issue creating and posting your message. Error: ", $e[0]);
            echo json_encode(statusMSG);
        }
?>
```

Comment: This worked beutifully had to edit your code a bit but like you said you didn't `test` it. I'm gonna add the fix to my code to show people my exact chnages... Thanks again cause I was about to put my fist through the computer lol

Comment: Glad it helped - I notice however you call the `execute` method twice in the changed code. Again - there should be no need to execute / query twice.

Comment: whoops. I my b.

Comment: Fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mysql version greater than or equal to 5.7 so you can use ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html

`mysql> SET @pt1 = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)');
mysql> SET @pt2 = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(180 0)');
mysql> SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(@pt1, @pt2);`

Output

```
ST_Distance_Sphere(@pt1, @pt2) 
 20015042.813723423
```

Distance in meters